# Including an automatically generated makefile as a trick to enforce execution of a recipe

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm slowly losing my mind here. First, let me describe what it is I'm trying to do.  We have a compiler that spews out weirdly formatted dependency files. To get these makefiles into a format GNU Make can understand, they need to be processed by a Perl script first. Technically, the Perl script doesn't *convert* the input dependency files it gets passed; instead it creates a new, properly formatted dependency file for each input dependency file.

Now, in order for GNU Make to know which translation units need recompiling and which don't, it obviously must have seen those dependency files before trying to make the translation unit targets, so we have the following line in our master makefile:

```
include $(PROCESSED_EXISTING_DEPENDENCY_FILES)
```

where `$(PROCESSED_EXISTING_DEPENDENCY_FILES)` is a list of all converted dependency files. My idea was to (ab-)use an automatically generated makefile whose recipe not only builds that makefile but also triggers the creation of all dependency files mentioned in the `$(PROCESSED_EXISTING_DEPENDENCY_FILES)` list and include that makefile just before including the converted dependency files. To ensure that the conversion takes place, the parent process of our Make process will delete the automatically created makefile first (we have a Perl wrapper process controlling GNU Make). The relevant part in the master makefile would look like this:

```
# Phony target that creates processed dependency files.
CONVERTED_EXISTING_DEPENDENCY_FILES :
    <recipe here>

$(PRE_CONVERTED_DEPENDENCY_FILE_INCLUSION_HOOK) : CONVERTED_EXISTING_DEPENDENCY_FILES
    $(info $(TARGET_BUILD_MESSAGE_PREFIX) Building $(notdir $@) ...)
    $(file >$@,# Automatically generated makefile that gets included before including the existing, converted dependency files.)
    $(file >>$@,$(DOLLAR)(info Including pre-converted-dependency-files-inclusion hook file ...))
    $(file >>$@,)

include $(PRE_CONVERTED_DEPENDENCY_FILE_INCLUSION_HOOK)
include $(PROCESSED_EXISTING_DEPENDENCY_FILES)
```

We're already using the same basic principle in several other cases, and so far this has worked perfectly fine, but for some reason when I try this, GNU Make gets lost in an infinite loop where it will continuously re-revaluate the master makefile, include all other makefiles and then go back to re-revaluating the master makefile again.

The `$(PRE_CONVERTED_DEPENDENCY_FILE_INCLUSION_HOOK)` does get created, and if there are any dependency files to be converted, they are processed, too, but I'm still at a loss as to what causes this infinite loop in Make. We are using GNU Make 4.2.1 for Windows on a Windows 10 (64 bit) system.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you rework your model completely to avoid any recipes that know how to build included files, and instead follow the model for auto-dependency generation described [in this post](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/) (based on how automake handles dependency generation).

Then add in the postprocessing step directly into the same recipe that generates the dependency files, rather than having a separate rule that does it.  I don't think it's necessary to have two separate rules because you really don't want the intermediate step here: you just want to generate the make prerequisites definitions... similar to how normally we wouldn't have separate rules for preprocessing, compiling, assembling object files: one rule does that even though there are multiple steps involved.